# javascript stop form submitting

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I have a login form that I am trying to handle with ajax.

At first appearance it works fine,

You click the login button,
if your details are correct you are logged in and redirected.

If your details are incorrect an error message is shown.

If you wait for the error message to disappear and click the login button again it works fine.

if you dont wait it seems to submit the form.
why does it do this?

here is the code

```
var timeout = null;

$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        var type = $(this).attr('method');
        $.ajax({
            url: action,
            type: type,
            data: {
                email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
                pass: $('input[name=pass]').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                switch (data.status) {
                    case false:
                        login_error(data.message);
                        return false;
                        break;
                    case true:
                        window.location = data.message;
                        return false;
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
});

function login_error(message) {
    $('form').effect('shake', { distance: 10, times: 3 }, 50);
    if (timeout !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $('#login').stop().hide();
        show_error(message);
    } else {
        show_error(message);
    }
}

function show_error(message) {
    $('#error').html(message)
            .show("drop", {direction: 'left'}, 500);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#error').hide("drop", {direction: 'right'}, 500);
        timeout = null;
    }, 5000);
}
```

---

**Edit**
Ok, so its not actually refreshing the page,

Something is setting the form to display:none;

I have added a whole pile of console.log()'s through the code and clicked login twice so it now looks like:

```
var timeout = null;

$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        console.log(1);
        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        console.log(2);
        var type = $(this).attr('method');
        console.log(3);
        $.ajax({
            url: action,
            type: type,
            data: {
                email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
                pass: $('input[name=pass]').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(4);
                switch (data.status) {
                    case false:
                            console.log(5);
                        login_error(data.message);
                        return false;
                        break;
                    case true:
                            console.log(6);
                        window.location = data.message;
                        return false;
                        break;
                }
                console.log(7);
                return false;
            }
        });
        console.log(8);
        return false;
    })
});

function login_error(message) {
    console.log(9);
    $('form').effect('shake', { distance: 10, times: 3 }, 50);
    console.log(10);
    if (timeout !== null) {
        console.log(11);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $('#login').stop().hide();
        console.log(12);
        show_error(message);
        console.log(13);
    } else {
        console.log(14);
        show_error(message);
        console.log(15);
    }
}

function show_error(message) {
    console.log(16);
    $('#error').html(message)
            .show("drop", {direction: 'left'}, 500);
    console.log(17);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(18);
        $('#error').hide("drop", {direction: 'right'}, 500);
        timeout = null;
    }, 5000);
    console.log(19);
}
```

With the output being:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   POST http://localhost/buzz/ajax/login 200 OK 30ms
>   8
>   4
>   5
>   9
>   10
>   14
>   16
>   17
>   19
>   15
>   **Second Click**
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   POST http://localhost/buzz/ajax/login 200 OK 30ms
>   8
>   4
>   5
>   9
>   10
>   11
>   12
>   16
>   17
>   19
>   13
>   18

Comment: An easy solution would be to make your error dialog modal.  Then the user would have to dismiss it before attempting to login again.  Another possibility is putting the error message right onto the web page, instead of using a dialog.

Comment: although practical, I personally think Modal dialogs are a crime against ui (except in certain cases e.g. lightbox for gallery) ;)

Comment: I agree with you, actually. Gosh, why did I even suggest it? :) That said, if you are going to use an error dialog, the proper way to do it is to make it modal. So for me, it's a choice between a modal dialog and no dialog at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One choice is to have a regular button, not a submit button. Use the onclick on the button you call your validation/ajax.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing it has to do with the animation of the form and/or #error not being completed.  You may want to make sure something has changed after a failed login.  So some `if/else` statements prior to submitting the form in code to make sure the form is submittable may make this work...  It probably would be a good idea to make sure there is a value for username and password prior to submitting the form....

Here is a quick sample of untested code, with some comments on changes...

```
$('form').submit(function() {
     //DEFINE "ISVALID()"....
     if($('input[name=pass]').val().ISVALID())
     {
         //your do login code here...
     }
     else
     {
         login_error("Please enter a password!");
     }
})
function login_error(message) {
    //CLEAR PASSWORD
    $('input[name=pass]').val() = "";
    //THE REST OF YOUR CODE HERE...
}
```

Comment: although it would save me a call to the server, I like to have all my error handing in one file :)

By the fact that the form is getting set to display:none makes me think you are right about the animations, the console.log output is also weird.

Comment: then put it all in one file...  but you are not validating anything at the moment, hence your issue...